# simulating rc4-256 with rc4-128

Tags: rc4

OpenSSL supports rc4 with 128-bit keys and rc4 with 40-bit keys. It does not support rc4 with 256-bit keys.

My question is...  is it possible to modify the state of the pseudo-random generation algorithm (PRGA), given a 128-bit key, to match the initial state a PRGA with a 256-bit key?

Comment: OpenSSL **library** supports any multiple of 8 bits key (i.e. integral bytes) for RC4 if you write a few lines of code to call it; it is the prewritten commandline utility `openssl enc -$cipher` alias `openssl $cipher` that supports only 40 and 128. And **libssl** also uses only 40 and 128 because those are the only published RC4 ciphersuites.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**NO**. Without changing the API, it is not possible to coerce a 40-bit-key or 128-bit-key implementation of RC4 to behave like a 256-bit-key one, because there is no way to inject any key material in the RC4 state after initialization.

[Dave_Thompson_085](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/users/12642/dave-thompson-085) has an interesting [comment](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/20442/555#comment47523_20442) for OpenSSL specifics.